# Switch wiring for 2 single pole switches and 2 different lights

Tags: electrical, switch, receptacle

Hi novice electrician,

Question- I have 2 lights, 2 switches and 2 receptacles but I put wired them weird. 12/2 wiring used FYI.

I put one switch with one receptacle and one switch with another receptacle.  Both receptacles are connected together.

When I turned on the lights they don’t work independently. If one is off, the other light is off. I know possibly because they share the same power source.

However I want it to function where If in the toilet closet, I can turn only that light on and then in the small closet in front of the toilet closet, I can turn on that light if I want to.

Both switches are not in the same box. Any ideas?

I know it’s something with the wiring at the switches and not at the receptacles I used. Both receptacles are correctly wired verified with my receptacle tool. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To make one switch the master switch, and always function one light:
Connect power to the inlet side and the outlet side directly to the light.  That light will always function with the master switch, regardless of the other switch position.

To get power to the other switch, run wires from the outlet side of the master switch (can use the push slots, or wire it with twist caps) to the inlet side of the closet switch. Then run wires from the outlet of the closet switch to the closet light.

Comment: Thank you for your help.   I just went ahead and moved the switch to be in the same box and it works now. I was making it too complicated for myself especially since the rooms are so close together.